# iOS direct printing to network printer

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, printing, bonjour

We look for a possibility to directly print to a printer on the network from an iPad application. We can't use AirPrint because the printing should be done programmatically and automatically in the background.
I found the printer pro app and some SDK of Epson, but no library that might be useful to achieve this.
Has anybody done this before? As a fallback, we would consider adding a fixed IP as the destination, hence avoiding to implement some networked printer detection mechanism.

Comment: Do you have a issue for that ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an iOS guy but you could use a fixed IP or try to resolve a printer name then connect via port 9100 and just send the data you want to print.  You would need to generate your own Postscript or PCL or other language the printer understands.  The good news is that many device these days support TIFF, JPEG, and PDF as native file formats so firing a document/image directly at the unit should produce output.